# Understanding Spring mvc produces/consumes and Jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-annotations

I am running a Spring MVC 3 maven app with embedded jetty with configuration below:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.14</version>
        <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <testClassesDirectory>/Users/mydownloads/Downloads/jackson-all-1.8.10.jar</testClassesDirectory>
            <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

As seen above, I have `jackson-all-1.8.10 jar` in the test classpath.

I have mappings like below which are working fine when I produce json from my controller:

`@RequestMapping(value="/getSomething",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.GET)`

However, when I try to have a `POST` mapping so then I get an error: `415: Unsupported Media Type`

the annotation I am using for POST is:

`@RequestMapping(value="/postSomething", consumes="application/json", method= RequestMethod.POST)`

How can I fix this so that the jackson jar sitting in the classpath takes care of the media type?

On the client when I am making a request to POST the data the request has following headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/myapp/postSomething
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
**Request Headersview source**
  Accept:*/*
  Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:23
  Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Cookie:JSESSIONID=1f0mox1qw67zl
  Host:localhost:8080
  Origin:http://localhost:8080
  Referer:http://localhost:8080/myapp/
  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I have `datatype: 'json'` on jQuery

Comment: check if content type of the request is set to correct value (`application/json`)

Comment: I have `datatype: 'json'` on the jquery side. I've also posted the request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the request `Content-Type` correctly.

As you can see in the headers you posted, the `Content-Type` header value is  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is jquery default.

Use `contentType: 'application/json'`  attribute in jquery ajax call.

The `dataType` attribute tells jquery what content type is to be expected in the response.